# How to properly calculate rational by using BigDecimal

Tags: java, precision, bigdecimal

How can I get the correct answer when I need to use BigDecimal without losing precision.

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(0.5);
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(30);
BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal(18000);

a.divide(b).multiply(c);
```

How could I get the exact 300 in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: just rearrange equation as you are loosing precision with rounding `c.divide(b).multiply(a) ==> 300.0`

Comment: Or you can find and use one of the BigRational classes on github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [MathContext](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/MathContext.html) parameter in the `divide` method for this.

For example, `a.divide(b, MathContext.DECIMAL128).multiply(c);` will give you the precision you need (with an error of magnitude `1e-32`). If you do not want to lose any precision, you can use `MathContext.UNLIMITED`, but this will result in a non-terminating decimal expansion.

In your case specifically, you can also try to rewrite the equation to prevent any rounding from happening: `a / b * c = c / b * a`.